# Adjusting the height of the border to an element using CSS

Tags: css

I;m trying to achieve the following via CSS:

[image]

These lines are connected to every div container inside a parent div-

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dynamic">
    some content some content some content
    some content some contentsome content
    some content some content some content
  </div>
  <div class="dynamic">
    other some content other some content other some content
     othersome content other some contentsome content
    other some content other some content some content
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    Add more content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
.dynamic .child3 {

  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

this is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/z6nget91/
however I'm stuck as to how can add lines to connect them to every container?
any ideas??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `::before` pseudo-element of the children to achieve that. You could start with something like this:

```css
.parent {
  border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -20px;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ff0000;
  width: 20px;
}

.child:last-child::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: -21px;
  top: calc(50% + 1px);
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    some content some content some content
    some content some contentsome content
    some content some content some content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    other some content other some content other some content
     othersome content other some contentsome content
    other some content other some content some content
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Add more content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @ajobi for the quick response. is there a way we can trim the line where the container list ends? i.e in the above screenshot- the line ends at the last container. is this doable form CSS as well?

Comment: It is yes (multiple ways), what you could do for example is use `:last-child` pseudo-class to target the last child, and use its `::after` pseudo element to "cover" the unwanted border part. That would be a quick albeit a bit "hacky" fix.

Comment: @user1234 I have updated the example to do exactly that ;-)

Comment: Thanks @ajobi, life saviour!! :)